# How can I programmatically change the active theme?

Tags: 8

How can I programmatically change the active Drupal 8 theme?

In Drupal 6, we used the following code.

```
global $custom_theme;
$custom_theme = 'garland';
```

In Drupal 7, we used `hook_custom_theme()`.

In Drupal 8, what's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Drupal 8, you use [theme negotiators](https://www.drupal.org/node/2158619), which essentially are services using a specific tag. See the theme negotiators implemented by Drupal, to understand exactly how they work; the example given in the change record is not updated.

#### [user.services.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.services.yml/8.8.x)

```
  theme.negotiator.admin_theme:
    class: Drupal\user\Theme\AdminNegotiator
    arguments: ['@current_user', '@config.factory', '@entity_type.manager', '@router.admin_context']
    tags:
      - { name: theme_negotiator, priority: -40 }
```

#### [AdminNegotiator.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!src!Theme!AdminNegotiator.php/8.8.x)

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\user\Theme;

use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\DeprecatedServicePropertyTrait;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\AdminContext;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeNegotiatorInterface;

/**
 * Sets the active theme on admin pages.
 */
class AdminNegotiator implements ThemeNegotiatorInterface {
  use DeprecatedServicePropertyTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected $deprecatedProperties = ['entityManager' => 'entity.manager'];

  /**
   * The current user.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface
   */
  protected $user;

  /**
   * The config factory.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface
   */
  protected $configFactory;

  /**
   * The entity type manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  /**
   * The route admin context to determine whether a route is an admin one.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Routing\AdminContext
   */
  protected $adminContext;

  /**
   * Creates a new AdminNegotiator instance.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $user
   *   The current user.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory
   *   The config factory.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
   *   The entity type manager.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Routing\AdminContext $admin_context
   *   The route admin context to determine whether the route is an admin one.
   */
  public function __construct(AccountInterface $user, ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory, EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, AdminContext $admin_context) {
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->configFactory = $config_factory;
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
    $this->adminContext = $admin_context;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    return ($this->entityTypeManager->hasHandler('user_role', 'storage') && $this->user->hasPermission('view the administration theme') && $this->adminContext->isAdminRoute($route_match->getRouteObject()));
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function determineActiveTheme(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    return $this->configFactory->get('system.theme')->get('admin');
  }

}
```

The code is pretty easy to understand: The `applies()` method returns `TRUE` when the current route is the one for which your module wants to change the theme; the `determineActiveTheme()` method returns the theme machine name of the theme to apply.

See also [ThemeNegotiator::determineActiveTheme() should not require a RouteMatch to be passed in](https://www.drupal.org/node/2292217) for a possible change on the arguments received from the methods used by theme negotiators; if that patch is applied, you will need to change your theme negotiator code too.
That issue's status has been *Needs work* since May 10, 2018; it has been also moved to Drupal 9.2.x on December 28, 2018. Drupal 8.9.x could not get that change back-ported and it's probably safe to say that a Drupal 8.x module needs to use the `RouteMatchInterface $route_match` parameter for `applies()`.

Comment: Shouldn't applies() be written as applies($route_match) in the above example? Posted the same question to the linked d.o. page. Thanks!

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis Hmmm... Any current implementation does get that as parameter, contrary to what that change record says.

Comment: I have updated the answer, using the code Drupal core is actually using in one of its theme negotiators.

Answer (score 4):

We have also a very nice and clean solution at https://git.drupalcode.org/project/mailsystem/blob/HEAD/src/MailsystemManager.php#n60

```
 // Switch the theme to the configured mail theme.
$mail_theme = $this->getMailTheme();
$current_active_theme = $this->themeManager->getActiveTheme();
if ($mail_theme && $mail_theme != $current_active_theme->getName()) {
  $this->themeManager->setActiveTheme($this->themeInitialization->initTheme($mail_theme));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution to this question is using the [Theme Switcher module](https://www.drupal.org/project/theme_switcher). 
it's compatible with Drupal 8 and 9 that developed by themeKey module developer.

> Theme Switcher module allows you to create theme-switching rules which
>   allow automatic selection of a theme based on Drupal 8 Conditions
>   system. Because of this it can also be easily extended to support
>   additional custom conditions exposed by other modules. In Drupal 8
>   conditions are no longer defined through a hook and they are plugins
>   now.
>
> With this module you can apply a specific theme to a unique node, use
>   different themes based on the page language, use contrib conditions
>   like a domain to apply one theme or another. The best of all is that
>   you can do al of the above at once!

Comment: Yep it's a good module, but behaves unexpectedly when multiple rules are applied