# Where does the theme name get stored in database?

Tags: theming, 8

In which table does Drupal 8 store the theme name?

I'm trying to programmatically install an uninstalled theme. Obviously, there's some written logic behind the *Install and set as default* button. What exactly does that button do?

Comment: What do you mean by "theme name"?

Comment: what do you mean active theme name? if true you can find it in table config with row name is system.theme. Data store is serialize. Data like that http://www.unserialize.com/s/0a62731a-cc5a-d8c8-1a76-00004200aea8

Comment: @MrD I am pretty sure she is dealing with an uninstalled theme name.

Answer (score 0):

The theme names are not stored in the db; other wise, we would have to uninstall the uninstalled themes... How would Drupal know the name of an uninstalled theme? It reads the names from the **themename.info.yml** file.

If you think about it, its just like uninstalled module names, the module name is not stored in the db, Drupal reads/gets the name from the module.info.yml file.

Comment: so what, if some one wants to install any theme PRO-GRAMMATICALLY? I know how to set default theme pro-grammatically  but can't figure out How to install it?

Comment: @SugandhKhanna that's a totally different Q than you initial Q. You should make a new Q regarding that. Off the top off my head, I don't know the answer to that since I've never had to deal with that scenario. You would have to do the programmatically equivalent of pressing the [Install and set as default](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MoY1Q.jpg) button.

Comment: I can't think of a scenario where the ability to "install any theme PRO-GRAMMATICALLY" makes sense. @SugandhKhanna could you clarify where and when your code will ever be in a position to make use of this? What is your goal?

Comment: My goal is like: I have a info.yml file where theme name is written, that I want to install, I will read this theme name from my .info.yml file and on a single button click, that theme will get installed. That same theme itself is present in theme folder of drupal.

Comment: Ok...but what does that have to do with your need to find the name of a theme in the database?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201530/how-can-i-change-the-active-theme-programmatically