# Alternative to ThemeKey?

Tags: theming, 8

I need to switch themes based on URL paths and content types. I would have used ThemeKey, but it's not in a ready state. What are people using in Drupal 8 to do these things?

Comment: You can do it using some custom coding. In Drupal 7, hook_custom_theme() was used to determine the theme to be used according to whichever conditions the developer wanted to set. In Drupal 8 this is done using theme negotiators: https://www.drupal.org/node/2158619

Comment: Here is a similar question to yours: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201530/how-can-i-change-the-active-theme-programmatically

Comment: take a look at this simplest solution: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/294377/7212