# Block visibility according to breakpoint

Tags: 8, blocks, theming

I have different blocks for different breakpoints and I hide blocks through CSS in media queries.

I have some images in blocks and I noticed that all these images is loaded even block is `display: none;`, and I don't want to load them on mobile for example.

So, I'm wondering is it possible somehow not to render block at all on some device width range (like media query) and not to do it through CSS?

Comment: see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230503/how-can-i-have-device-specific-block-layouts