# How to change active theme based on taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, theme-negotiation

I have a situation where I need to change the active theme based on whether the current entity has a certain taxonomy tag. So when an entity is viewed and tagged with *candy*, I would like the Candy theme to be activated.

My research has lead me to believe that the easiest way to achieve this is to implement a theme negotiator in a similar way to the example given [here](https://www.webomelette.com/choose-your-theme-dynamically-drupal-8-theme-negotiation).

I am able to switch the active theme based on the route and also the current uri, the problem is getting the theme to switch based on a taxonomy tag. I am not sure how to get the taxonomy tags for the current entity from within the theme negotiator. I would like to be able to do something similar to the following.

```
public function determineActiveTheme(routeMatchInterface $route_match) {
  // Get the current taxonomy tags.
  if (tag_exists) {
    return 'candy_theme';
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the active theme programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201530/how-can-i-change-the-active-theme-programmatically)

Comment: The recent dev releases of the [context module](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) (8.x-1.x-dev) have support for changing themes based on other context. I am just not certain if it has a condition for taxonomies... Would be a perfect non-programming solution for your problem though.