# How can I set a different theme basing on the language currently used for the page?

Tags: 8, theming, multi-sites

We have built one website in English and we want to translate it in Arabic.

Since I am new to Drupal, I am not sure how I can set a theme for English, and one for Arabic. How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can check the current language with the languageManager ([docs here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AlanguageManager/8.4.x))

```
Drupal::languageManager()
```

and then you can set a different theme with the theme service

```
\Drupal::service('theme_handler')->setDefault('test_theme');
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Maybe adding such code in a "hook_init" into a custom module, so that the theme gets automatically defined when the page loads according to the language should do the job

Comment: In D8 this would be in a theme negotiator, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201530/how-can-i-change-the-active-theme-programmatically

Comment: @lchabrand Thanks for your answer. Which file to add above code. I know about themename.theme file or this can only go in module file. I am new to drupal 8 and will try to learn making modules if this code can only go in theme file.